# Why does vim show ^? when I press the backspace key?

Tags: keyboard, vim

In one of my remote machines, I try to use `vim` to edit a file.

When I press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, the output is not deleting my character but adding `^?` which is in a different color.

What is this and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I assumed you meant the backspace key, is that correct? Also, where are you connecting from (which Terminal?), and where are you connecting to?

Comment: ^ What he said + which shell are you using and what is the value of the ``$TERM`` environment variable? (``echo $TERM``).

Comment: i am connecting to a remote machine. i echo $TERM, it is xterm. My term in local is gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [known bug](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154090) in Xterm which produced the wrong backspace character.. Upgrading to the latest version of XTerm should fix the issue. Otherwise, you can use a workaround the issue by adding

```
*ttyModes: erase ^?
```

to /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm.